# Weird SMB mount issue - cannot mount from fstab

Tags: mount, samba, fstab, automount

I am running a NAS box with a smb share `//192.168.1.16/media`

The share is available from all Windows and Android clients.

On Ubuntu PCs it can be accessed with file browsers like Nemo or Nautilus as `smb://192.168.1.16/media`

However, on the Ubuntu (14.04) PCs the share cannot be mounted from `fstab`. The `fstab` line is

```
//192.168.1.16/media  /mnt/readynas  cifs  username=validuser,password=validpassword  0 0
```

which on `sudo mount -a` returns:

```
mount: special device //192.168.1.16/media does not exist
```

Clearly, the device does exist.

Any clues, hints or tips?

Answer (score 1):

OK, solved it. I needed to add

```
sec=ntlm
```

to the mount options in the `fstab` line.

Comment: Could you please add a little bit more instructions so that the next newbie on the block (No, I'm not including *you* in that category) can do this all by him/her/itself as well?  :-)

Comment: I had to add this options on Ubuntu 14.04. But it doesn't work when copied to in a new Ubuntu 20.04. Removed `sec=ntlm` and it works on the new distro.